# Android app - Information screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an android app that is going to be used on a information screen. This app contains 5 (weather, next run, opening hours, etc...) activities, the plan is to loop through these activities with a timeinterval. So it starts with first activity, sleeps for like 5 seconds and then jump to next activity, and when it comes to the last activity, it should start in the front again.

What is the best solution to create a navigation system like this? Have Android some special features for things like this, or is the default `startActivity()` the only way?

And there is a little twist with this, some of the activities needs to retrive data from external sources by `HTTP`. So the activities must be done with data-query before it starts the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You use startActivity to swap between activities. After you are finished with an activity, remember to call `finish()` - otherwise there will be a lot of instances of the same activity.

But if you want something like an information screen, you could use a single activity but use Fragments. That way you simply inflate a single fragment, and keep a timer to swap between them. You can still show the same content, but there are some differences between activity and fragment in inflating and finding the views by id.